# Put Conky behind the desktop icons

Tags: linux, conky

Maybe I am trying do something impossible, but after hours of Googling I didn't get 100% answer yet.

So - it is possible put Conky on Desktop backgroud (behind desktop icons)?

The usual config:

```
own_window yes
own_window_type normal # (desktop, override) - I have the same result for all this attributes
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorated,below,skip_taskbar,sticky,skip_pager
```

Is giving me Conky with (pseudo)transparent background in front of icons (they are completely hidden behind it, even if in background of Conky is shown background image), while I am trying achieve opposite...

My system:

- SuSE 11.4
- KDE 4.4 (Release 3)
- x86_64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo-transparency of conky is achieved by repainting the part of the wallpaper that is covered by conky. Therefore conky can't show desktop icons behind it.

Note that conky is a normal window whithout border and titlebar.

You can, however, make a screenshot of your Desktop without conky and use it as wallpaper so you can see the desktop icons behind conky, but you won't be able to click on them.

Comment: I've been afraid of this. Pity, it would be nice if Conky would really work on Desktop background, so it wouldn't interfere with workspace at all - and still be showing nice things as a callendar...

Comment: What kind of cruel prison is this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. you **CAN** do this.

```
own_window_argb_visual yes
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: Can you provide more  information on how this is done specifically?

Comment: In this case you can not drag the icons

Answer (score 1):

After trying to work around this issue for a long time I've finally got my desktop icons working normally with conky overlapping them. Turns out the issue was the new syntax.

My conkyrc had originally had `own_window_type = 'desktop'` (which is the new syntax) but changing it to `own_window_type desktop` allowed my desktop icons to become clickable through the conky overlap.

If `own_window_type desktop` doesn't work for you then try `own_window_type = 'desktop',`.